# Arduino - how to concatenate byte arrays to get a final array

Tags: arduino

I have the following Arduino function:

```
void SendCommandToDisplay(byte message[], byte size) 
{ 
    byte header[] = {0x5A, 0xA5};
    byte result[] = {};
    memcpy(result, header, sizeof(header));
    memcpy(result+sizeof(header), message, size);

    for (byte i=0; i<sizeof(result); i++)
    {
      Serial.print(result[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(' ');
    }

}
```

Then I call this function as follows:

```
 byte test[]={0x82, 0x20, 0x10, 0x00, 0x03};
 SendCommandToDisplay(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(byte));
```

And seems is not working, I'm doing something wrong or maybe I have to do a reference or pointer. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory for the `result` variable - in your case try this:

```
void SendCommandToDisplay(byte message[], byte size) 
{ 
    byte header[] = {0x5A, 0xA5};
    byte result[sizeof(header)+size];
    memcpy(result, header, sizeof(header));
    memcpy(result+sizeof(header), message, size);

    for (byte i=0; i<sizeof(result); i++)
    {
        Serial.print(result[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(' ');
    }

}
```

Once simple approach to inserting the byte count (of message) following header is to change how the header is initialized:

```
byte header[] = {0x5A, 0xA5, size};
```

Note: a prior edit added an alternative to use the `sizeof(message)` but that was incorrect and removed - sizeof(message) where `message` is a parameter returns the sizeof of a pointer which is 2 on an arduino.

Comment: Very nice, do you know how can I append to the byte array the size of the message in HEX? So if message size is 5 append after header the size like 0x05?